# Websockets with Phalcon

Tags: php, websocket, phalcon

Is it possible to use Phalcon to both serve pages and run as a websockets server?

When building my web applications it would be preferential to do all the server side coding within the same framework.

If it's possible can you explain how to set it up or provide a tutorial link(s)?

If it's not possible can you recommend a PHP based framework that is designed for both purposes?

Thanks!

Comment: If you mean writing a WebSockets daemon from scratch, it is possible with any PHP frameworks. Otherwise, you may need a library/component addon such as Ratchet - http://socketo.me/

Comment: Go with a fully built websocket solution, such as https://pusher.com/
It has a free tier, so you can experiment as much as you want

Comment: doesn't have anything to do with Phalcon. What the guys in the comments say is correct, just use a 3rd party abstraction library.

Answer (score 0):

The Phalcon CLI Task

```
<?php
namespace Project\Cli\Tasks;

use ZMQ,
    PDO,
    React\ZMQ\Context as ZMQContext,
    React\EventLoop\Factory as EventLoopFactory,
    Ratchet\Server\IoServer,
    Ratchet\Http\HttpServer,
    Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer,
    Ratchet\Session\SessionProvider,
    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler,
    Webird\Cli\TaskBase,
    Webird\Cli\Chat;

/**
 * Task for websocket
 *
 */
class ServiceTask extends TaskBase
{
    public function mainAction(array $params)
    {
        echo "The default action inside of the ", CURRENT_TASK, " task is not configured\n";
    }

    public function websocketListenAction(array $params)
    {
        // $this->ensureRunningAsWebUser();
        $opts = $params['opts'];
        $config = $this->config;

        $wsPort = (isset($opts['wsport'])) ? $opts['wsport'] : $config->app->wsPort;
        $zmqPort = (isset($opts['zmqport'])) ? $opts['zmqport'] : $config->app->zmqPort;

        $loop = EventLoopFactory::create();
        $chat = new Chat();
        $chat->setDI($this->getDI());

        // Listen for the web server to make a ZeroMQ push after an ajax request
        // $context = new ZMQContext($loop);
        // $pull = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
        // $pull->bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:${zmqPort}"); // Binding to 127.0.0.1 means the only client that can connect is itself
        // $pull->on('message', [$chat, 'onUserJoin']);

        $wsServer = new WsServer($chat);

        $ioServer = IoServer::factory(
            new HttpServer($wsServer),
            $wsPort
        );

        echo "websocket listening on port $wsPort in " . ENVIRONMENT . " mode\n";

        $ioServer->run();
    }

}
```

The Chat application for Ratchet

```
<?php
namespace Webird\Cli;

use Phalcon\DI\Injectable as DIInjectable,
    Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface,
    Ratchet\ConnectionInterface,
    Webird\DatabaseSessionReader;

/**
 * Basic chat logic for a Ratchet application
 */
class Chat extends DIInjectable implements MessageComponentInterface
{

    protected $clients;

    /**
     * Class constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage();
    }

    /**
     * Connection open function
     *
     * @param \Ratchet\ConnectionInterface  $conn
     */
    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn)
    {
try {
        echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";

        $cookies = $conn->WebSocket->request->getCookies();
        if (! array_key_exists('PHPSESSID', $cookies)) {
            echo "Connection Rejected: Session Cookie was not present.\n";
            return $conn->close();
        }
        $sessionId = $cookies['PHPSESSID'];

        $sessionReader = $this->getDI()->getSessionReader();
        if ($sessionReader->read($sessionId) === false) {
            echo "Connection Rejected: Session could not be found.\n";
            return $conn->close();
        }
        if (($identity = $sessionReader->get('auth-identity')) === false) {
            echo "Connection Rejected: session auth-identity data is not present.\n";
            return $conn->close();
        }
        if (!isset($identity['role'])) {
            echo "Connection Rejected: session user role data is not present.\n";
            return $conn->close();
        }

        $role = $identity['role'];
        $acl = $this->getDI()->getAcl();

        if (!$this->acl->isAllowed($role, 'websocket', 'open')) {
            echo "Connection Rejected: user does not have permission to open a websocket.\n";
            return $conn->close();
        }

} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}

        // var_export($sessionReader->get('id'));
        // var_export($sess);

        // Store the new connection to send messages to later
        $this->clients->attach($conn, $sessionId);
    }

    /**
     * Receives a message when registered in the websocket server
     *
     * @param \Ratchet\ConnectionInterface  $from
     * @param string                        $msg
    */
    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
        $numRecv = $this->clients->count() - 1;

        // echo $from->Session->getName() . "\n";

        echo sprintf('Connection %d sending message "%s" to %d other connection%s' . "\n"
            , $from->resourceId, $msg, $numRecv, $numRecv == 1 ? '' : 's');

        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            if ($from !== $client) {
                // The sender is not the receiver, send to each client connected
                $client->send($msg);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handle closing of a connection
     *
     * @param \Ratchet\ConnectionInterface  $conn
    */
    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // The connection is closed, remove it, as we can no longer send it messages
        $this->clients->detach($conn);

        echo "Connection {$conn->resourceId} has disconnected\n";
    }

    /**
     * Handles exceptions in the application
     *
     * @param \Ratchet\ConnectionInterface  $from
     * @param \Exception                    $e
    */
    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
        echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";

        $conn->close();
    }

}
```

The read-only Database session reader.

```
<?php
namespace Webird;

use Phalcon\Db;

/**
 * Read-only session access
 *
 */
class DatabaseSessionReader
{
    private $options;

    private $data;

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     *
     * @param  array                      $options
     * @throws \Phalcon\Session\Exception
     */
    public function __construct($options = null)
    {
        if (!isset($options['db'])) {
            throw new \Exception("The parameter 'db' is required");
        }
        if (!isset($options['unique_id'])) {
            throw new \Exception("The parameter unique_id is required");
        }
        if (!isset($options['db_table'])) {
            throw new \Exception("The parameter 'db_table' is required");
        }
        if (!isset($options['db_id_col'])) {
            throw new \Exception("The parameter 'db_id_col' is required");
        }
        if (!isset($options['db_data_col'])) {
            throw new \Exception("The parameter 'db_data_col' is required");
        }
        if (!isset($options['db_time_col'])) {
            throw new \Exception("The parameter 'db_time_col' is required");
        }

        $this->options = $options;
        $this->data = false;
    }

    protected function getOptions()
    {
        return $this->options;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @param  string $sessionId
     * @return string
     */
    public function read($sessionId)
    {
        $options = $this->getOptions();
        $row = $options['db']->fetchOne(
            sprintf(
                'SELECT %s FROM %s WHERE %s = ?',
                $options['db']->escapeIdentifier($options['db_data_col']),
                $options['db']->escapeIdentifier($options['db_table']),
                $options['db']->escapeIdentifier($options['db_id_col'])
            ),
            Db::FETCH_NUM,
            [$sessionId]
        );

        $this->data = (empty($row[0])) ? false : $this->unserialize_php($row[0]);

        return ($this->data !== false);
    }

    public function has($key)
    {
        if (!is_string($key)) {
            throw new \Exception('The key must be a string');
        }

        if ($this->data == false) {
            return false;
        }

        $uniqueId = $this->getOptions()['unique_id'];
        return (array_key_exists("{$uniqueId}{$key}", $this->data));
    }

    public function get($key)
    {
        if (!$this->has($key)) {
            return false;
        }

        $uniqueId = $this->getOptions()['unique_id'];
        return $this->data["{$uniqueId}{$key}"];
    }

    private function unserialize_php($session_data)
    {
        $return_data = array();
        $offset = 0;
        while ($offset < strlen($session_data)) {
            if (!strstr(substr($session_data, $offset), "|")) {
                throw new \Exception("invalid data, remaining: " . substr($session_data, $offset));
            }
            $pos = strpos($session_data, "|", $offset);
            $num = $pos - $offset;
            $varname = substr($session_data, $offset, $num);
            $offset += $num + 1;
            $data = unserialize(substr($session_data, $offset));
            $return_data[$varname] = $data;
            $offset += strlen(serialize($data));
        }
        return $return_data;
    }

}
```

Here is the DI to setup the session reader.

```
$di->set('sessionReader', function() use ($di) {
    $config = $di->get('config');
    $connection = $di->get('db');

    $sessionReader = new DatabaseSessionReader([
        'db'          => $connection,
        'unique_id'    => $config->session->unique_id,
        'db_table'    => $config->session->db_table,
        'db_id_col'   => $config->session->db_id_col,
        'db_data_col' => $config->session->db_data_col,
        'db_time_col' => $config->session->db_time_col,
        'uniqueId'    => $config->session->unique_id
    ]);

    return $sessionReader;
});
```

Ref: https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/3539/phalcon-websockets